# Access nested template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently facing an issue with a nested template parameter which I'd like to access, but I'm not sure whether this is even possible. Here is a description of the problem:

I have a class "Histogram" from a library, which I have no influence on. The class looks like:

```
template<int N>
struct Histogram
{
  float histogram[N];
  static int descriptorSize() { return N; }
};
```

Now I want to create my own class for principal component analysis which should be able to process histograms of arbitrary sizes:

```
template<template<typename> class HistogramT> 
class PCA {

  // I'd like to pass on the nested template parameter here
  typedef typename Matrix< float , N , N > MatrixNf;

  // ...
}
```

The final instantiation of the class would look like:

```
PCA<Histogram<153> > pca;
```

My question now is how, or even if, it is possible to access the template parameter N of `Histogram<int N>` inside of my PCA class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do:

```
PCA<Histogram<153> > pca;
```

Then `PCA` should be:

```
template <typename Histogram>
class PCA { ... };
```

since `Histogram<153>` is a full type, not a template. As to how to get the number? Just write a type trait:

```
template <typename T> struct get_histogram_size;

template <int N>
struct get_histogram_size<Histogram<N> > {
    static const int value = N;
}
```

Usage:

```
template <typename Histogram>
class PCA { 
    static const int N = get_histogram_size<Histogram>::value;
    typedef typename Matrix< float , N , N > MatrixNf;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I think this is the most generic solution since the traits can be extended without touching the PCA class. So any "type" can be passed to the PCA class as long as it behaves the same like the Histogram class.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class T> 
class PCA;

template <int N> 
class PCA<Histogram<N> >
{
    typedef typename Matrix< float , N , N > MatrixNf;
    // ...
};

PCA<Histogram<153> > pca;
```

Comment: unfortunately I can only accept one answer, I just wanted to point out that your answer is perfectly valid. The reason I didn't choose yours is that it limits the PCA class to types which must be castable to the Histogram class. Otherwise I would need to do create another specialized PCA class and reimplement it - which usually is ok but in this case the class is a well defined algorithm and only depends on the vector dimension N. So the specialization for another class would be almost a 1:1 copy.

Answer (score 1):

First, your template template parameter is incorrect. It should have `int` rather than `typename` in it

```
template<template<int> class HistogramT> 
class PCA
```

But now you can't write

```
PCA<Histogram<154>>
```

because `Histogram<154>` is not a template, it's a class. I suggest that you simply add another parameter, like this:

```
template<template<int> class HistogramT, int N> 
class PCA
```

And use

```
PCA<Histogram, 154>
```

The Histogram template is not written very well. If it were, it would provide something like:

```
static const int size = N;
```

inside, so that you could do:

```
 template<class HistT>
    class PCA
    {
        //here, use HistT::size for N.
    }
```